# $(this).css("background", "transparent"); is not working in IE

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

Please help :

`$(this).css("background", "transparent");` is not working in IE (7 and 8).

Thank You.

Comment: Please post your code in the forum or try to set background-image: none; with background-color: transparent;

Comment: it is link tag <a href=""></a>.

Comment: $('.menuhovercl').hover(function(){
 $(this).css('background', '#B7F2F7');  
 }, function() {
  $(this).css("background", "transparent");
 });

Comment: Using the code from your comment, it works fine in IE7/8: http://jsfiddle.net/NSVzE/. You need to provide more information - your HTML/CSS, or a jsFiddle demo.

Comment: I had this issue too, I have no idea why

Comment: For all of you whiners out there, there is no more information to give :P it simply doesn't work and actually causes some crazy page redirection, but only on the remote server, not my local test env

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working just fine in IE 7 and IE 8.

I tested this in actual IE 7 and IE 8 browsers, and it does work: [jsfiddle.net/4L9RX/](http://jsfiddle.net/4L9RX/)

If you have a situation where it doesn't work, you have to show enough of your code that it's repeatable.

Comment: Have you checked this code ? $('.menuhovercl').hover(function(){ $(this).css('background', '#B7F2F7'); }, function() { $(this).css("background", "transparent"); });

Comment: @Saki Make: Now I have. It also works just fine in IE 7 and IE 8.